# Unable to copy files on iPod

Tags: ipod

Until 2 days ago my iPod was playing music and videos just fine.

Now suddenly it is unable to copy multiple video files together from the library. It copies only when videos are given to it in groups of 3 or 4.

The iPod is also unable to copy any music from the library. Sometimes it copies just a few of the selected files and then hangs the computer. It doesn't even eject and eventually I have to just disconnect it!

I am very puzzled to see these problems with my iPod classic (120 GB).

Comment: Have you tried to sync two accounts to your iPod at once? Are all of your files belonging to you?

Comment: @Odinulf What 2 accounts are you referring to?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean... Elaborate your comment...

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of iPod is this? iPod Touch? iPod Classic...

Apple recommends the following steps to troubleshoot iPod issues. Exactly how these steps are performed will depend upon which iPod and OS you're using:

1. Reset the iPod
2. Retry connecting. Use a different USB port and cable.
3. Restart your computer. Make sure you have the latest software
   updates installed
4. Reinstall the latest version of iTunes and the iPod software. Connect the iPod and select
   "Check for Updates" in the iPod's source page.
5. Restore the iPod. This erases everything and takes it back to its factory state.

These are the same troubleshooting steps taken at Apple retail stores. They will fix the vast majority of iPod issues. If they don't, the device has likely experienced hardware failure of some kind. If it's still under warranty you can ask Apple to replace it.

For advice on the above steps specific to your device you can visit [Apple's iPod troubleshooting site](http://www.apple.com/support/ipod/).

Comment: Mine is a 120GB Classic (Black).  I guess I have tried most of the steps you have proposed except probably of reloading the iPod software.

Comment: That's the step that usually fixes it, if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The repeated failure of large video files is also a symptom of a failing hard drive or directory corruption. You might try to erase the iPod using Disk Utility on mac or Windows Disk Manager.

If the drive is having issues, you might be doing nothing wrong on the iTunes end of things.